# Cannot access webmin newly installed Google Compute LEMP VM

Tags: google-compute-engine, webmin, google-cloud-platform

I have just set a VM instance on Google Compute, using the LEMP image.

I am able to access via gcloud ssh and installed webmin, I see webmin is running

```
sudo service webmin status gives
Webmin (pid 2539) is running
```

I changed default port to 1011 touching this two parameters

```
port=1011
listen=1011
```

if I do a wget to the localhost:1011 I get 200 response telling need to use ssl

I also on network on the google cloud console added a firewall rule to accept udp and tcp connection to port 1011, but "web page not available shows" when hitting `http://externalip:1011`  same for https.

I don´t know what else to do, any ideas ?

thanks

Comment: My Webmin on Debian GCE works on port 1011, please double check the firewall rule is on the same network of instance.
You can try to add  allow=0.0.0.0 to /etc/webmin/miniserv.conf

Comment: Thanks, I manage to make it work via adding the rule via gcutil and not via the web site, weird but that is how i solved..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add the firewall rule, you specify a tag. You need to specify the same tag for your VM.

See the second response here:  [How to open a specific port such as 9090 in Google Compute Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21065922/how-to-open-a-specific-port-such-as-9090-in-google-compute-engine)