# RStudio Server, Shiny app doesn't launch, the app's page goes grey immediately

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, rstudio-server, httpuv

Shiny apps used to run perfectly before the update of packages and RStudio server (shiny (1.3.2) and httpuv (1.5.1)). The app's page goes grey inmediately after running the app.

I have tried this https://community.rstudio.com/t/shiny-v1-3-known-regressions-and-serious-issues/28180/4 , but it still doesn't work.
I also tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/27113322/10004051 and it works, but I will like to not include that extra code.

Example with errors:

```
shiny::runExample("01_hello")
```

It works with this workaround:

```
runExample("01_hello", host="0.0.0.0", port=9999)
```

This is my session info:

```
> devtools::session_info()
─ Session info ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 setting  value                                      
 version  R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)               
 os       Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.6 (Maipo)
 system   x86_64, linux-gnu                          
 ui       RStudio                                    
 language (EN)                                       
 collate  en_US.UTF-8                                
 ctype    en_US.UTF-8                                
 tz       Europe/Madrid                              
 date     2019-08-19                                 
─ Packages ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 package     * version date       lib source        
 assertthat    0.2.1   2019-03-21 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 backports     1.1.4   2019-04-10 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 callr         3.3.1   2019-07-18 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 cli           1.1.0   2019-03-19 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 crayon        1.3.4   2017-09-16 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 crosstalk     1.0.0   2016-12-21 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 curl          4.0     2019-07-22 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 data.table    1.12.2  2019-04-07 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 desc          1.2.0   2018-05-01 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 devtools      2.1.0   2019-07-06 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 digest        0.6.20  2019-07-04 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 dplyr       * 0.8.3   2019-07-04 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 DT          * 0.8     2019-08-07 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 fs            1.3.1   2019-05-06 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 glue          1.3.1   2019-03-12 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 htmltools     0.3.6   2017-04-28 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 htmlwidgets   1.3     2018-09-30 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 httpuv        1.5.1   2019-04-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 jsonlite      1.6     2018-12-07 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 later         0.8.0   2019-02-11 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 lubridate   * 1.7.4   2018-04-11 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 magrittr      1.5     2014-11-22 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 markdown      1.1     2019-08-07 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 memoise       1.1.0   2017-04-21 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 mime          0.7     2019-06-11 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 pillar        1.4.2   2019-06-29 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 pkgbuild      1.0.4   2019-08-05 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 pkgconfig     2.0.2   2018-08-16 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 pkgload       1.0.2   2018-10-29 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 plyr          1.8.4   2016-06-08 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 prettyunits   1.0.2   2015-07-13 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 processx      3.4.1   2019-07-18 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 promises      1.0.1   2018-04-13 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 ps            1.3.0   2018-12-21 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 purrr         0.3.2   2019-03-15 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 R6            2.3.0   2018-10-04 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 Rcpp          1.0.2   2019-07-25 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 remotes       2.1.0   2019-06-24 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 RevoUtils   * 11.0.3  2019-05-10 [2] local         
 rJava         0.9-11  2019-03-29 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 rlang         0.4.0   2019-06-25 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 rprojroot     1.3-2   2018-01-03 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 rstudioapi    0.10    2019-03-19 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 sessioninfo   1.1.1   2018-11-05 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 shiny       * 1.3.2   2019-04-22 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 shinyjs     * 1.0     2018-01-08 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 stringi       1.4.3   2019-03-12 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 stringr       1.4.0   2019-02-10 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 testthat      2.2.1   2019-07-25 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 tibble        2.1.3   2019-06-06 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 tidyselect    0.2.5   2018-10-11 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 usethis       1.5.1   2019-07-04 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 withr         2.1.2   2018-03-15 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 xfun          0.8     2019-06-25 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 xlsx        * 0.6.1   2018-06-11 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 xlsxjars      0.6.1   2014-08-22 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 xtable        1.8-4   2019-04-21 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 yaml          2.2.0   2018-07-25 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.3)

[1] /home/aaa17679/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5
[2] /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.3/lib64/R/library
```

And this is my RStudio server info:

```
> RStudio.Version()

$mode
[1] "server"

$version
[1] ‘1.2.1335’
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is related to a misconfiguration of the proxy of the RServer as it is described in:

https://community.rstudio.com/t/shiny-v1-3-known-regressions-and-serious-issues/28180/4.

You have to update your proxy configuration with the following article as guide:

https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200552326-Running-RStudio-Server-with-a-Proxy