# Open ports for Cassandra in Google Cloud Comput production environment

Tags: cassandra, firewall, server, production, google-cloud-platform

I've been working with Storm topologies and Cassandra databases for relatively short period of time.
 I recently realized that my development environment's spec is not strong enough for my testing, so I deployed a 3-node Cassandra cluster on Google Cloud instance.
 Now I'd like to let Storm topology (hosted on a separate box) to insert into Cassandra.
 Obviously, this feature is not enabled by default, and I'd like to have a guideline of how to, **securely**, open Cassandra for database queries from different IP in production scenario. ( I suspect that Google protects its instances with a firewall as well?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Carlos Rojas's directions in [THIS LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21065922/how-to-open-a-specific-port-such-as-9090-in-google-compute-engine), I could open the ports to access Cassandra from outside the network computer. Also, you can open ports in your firewall using this line :
`gcutil addfirewall cassandra-rule --allowed="tcp:9042,tcp:9160" --network="default" --description="Allow external Cassandra Thrift/CQL connections"` from [THIS LINK](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-cassandra-python)

Comment: Thanks. would I need to apply the above rule for both egress and ingress paths?

Comment: thanks. It gave me some direction but I am still not able to work gcp and cassandra work on external IP. Can you please take a look at -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59393296/error-when-running-cassandra-on-google-cloud-on-external-ip-failed-to-bind-por