# Container Optimized OS Examples

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-container-os

I've followed all the documentation here: https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/ to try to upgrade my existing configuration that used container-vm images that have now been deprecated, to a new configuration using container-optimized OS. But nothing works! I can't get the Docker container to bind to port 80 (ie. -p 80:80) and also my Docker container can't seem to write to /var/run/nginx.pid (yes I'm using nginx in my Docker container). I followed the instructions to disable AppArmour and I've also tried creating an AppArmour profile for nginx. Nothing works! Are they any examples out there using container-optimized OS that don't just use busybox image and print "Hello World" or sleep! How about an example that opens a port and writes to the file system?

Comment: -v 80:80 should be -p 80:80 .. typo?

Comment: @koma fixed thanks

Answer (score 3):

I just installed [Apache Guacamole](https://guacamole.incubator.apache.org/) on Container Optimized OS and it works like a charm. There are [some constraints in place for security](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/concepts/security).

The root filesystem ("/") is mounted as read-only with some portions of it re-mounted as writable, as follows:

- /tmp, /run, /media, /mnt/disks and /var/lib/cloud are all mounted
  using tmpfs and, while they are writable, their contents are not
  preserved between reboots.
- Directories /mnt/stateful_partition, /var
  and /home are mounted from a stateful disk partition, which means
  these locations can be used to store data that persists across
  reboots. For example, Docker's working directory /var/lib/docker is
  stateful across reboots.
- Among the writable locations, only
  /var/lib/docker and /var/lib/cloud are mounted as "executable" (i.e.
  without the noexec mount flag).

[If you need to accept HTTP (port 80) connections from any source IP](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/how-to/firewall) address, run the following commands on your Container-Optimzied OS instance:

```
sudo iptables -w -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

In general, it is recommended you configure the host firewall as a systemd service through cloud-init.

PS: Container-Optimized OS is capable of auto updates. This mechanism can be used to update a fleet of Compute Engine instances.

Comment: Thanks. I believe I couldn't even bind to 80... I'll take a look tonight.

Comment: I am binding to port 80 without issue, that is I am port mappning a service in Docker to port 80 using -p 80:8080.

Answer (score 1):

> I can't get the Docker container to bind to port 80 (ie. -p 80:80) and also my Docker container can't seem to write to /var/run/nginx.pid (yes I'm using nginx in my Docker container).

I think you might be hitting some GCE firewall problem. The best way would be to verify/debug it step by step:

1. Try running a stupidly simple nginx container:
   "-d" asks Docker to run it in daemon mode, "-p 80:80" maps the HTTP port, and "--name nginx-hello" names to container to nginx-hello.

   ```
   docker run -d --name nginx-hello -p 80:80 nginx
   ```
2. (optional) Verifies that the container is running correctly: You should see the "nginx-hello" container listed.

   ```
   docker ps
   ```
3. Verifies that nginx is working locally: You should see a good HTTP response.

   ```
   curl localhost:80
   ```

If you are able to verify all the above steps correctly, then you would likely be facing a GCE firewall problem:

[How do I enable http traffic for GCE instance templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31509722/how-do-i-enable-http-traffic-for-gce-instance-templates)