# SSL certificate for the ip adress [Nginix+django server]

Tags: django, nginx, google-cloud-platform, ssl-certificate, virtual-machine

I have nginix+django server on google cloud virtual machine which is running at a specific port(8080). I am able to access the service by http://external_ip:8080. But I'm not able to access it over "https". I dont have a domain name. For our application it is not necessary as it is just a rest api to perform some tasks. I am relatively new to these terms like ssl certificate, domain name, nginix ... etc. It would be great if someone can help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two paths:

1. Configure [Nginx to serve on 443 with TLS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-an-ssl-certificate-on-nginx-for-ubuntu-14-04). Configure GCP firewall [to allow for https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31509722/how-do-i-enable-http-traffic-for-gce-instance-templates) with tags.
2. With tags, configure FW rules for the instance to only serve 8080 to GCP Load Balancers and [have HTTP(S) Load Balancing](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/) serve the content via TLS to the public.

In any case you'll have annoying TLS issues without a DNS name - so you should get one. You should alternatively look into [serving Django from App Engine Standard](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/).