# "unable to connect" to java web application on glassfish 4 server using google cloud computing

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, google-cloud-platform, glassfish-4, java-ee-7

**Problem:**

when I try to load my java web applicaton that resides on a glassfish 4 server from a remote web browser, i get the "`problem loading ...`"   "`unable to connect`"  page showing up in my browser.  I tried port 8080 and 4848, both with no success.

**Additional details about the issue:**

I have deployed a .war java web application to the context root "/".

I have one domain running.

mostly, i use command line only.

i am using debian jessie server on a google cloud computing virtual machine instance.

In the glassfish troubleshooting guide, I discovered that I had not set the PATH environment variable to the JDK/bin directory, so I properly set the PATH environment variable, yet it did not solve the issue.

Comment: Have you tried open the 8080 and 4848 ports for the firewall configuration in compute engine? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21065922/how-to-open-a-specific-port-such-as-9090-in-google-compute-engine

Comment: no.  i have not tried that.  i will first re-install glassfish, then if that didn't work, i will follow your link that explains how to open specific ports.

Comment: Did your server ever run? As in before you tried to deploy an app.

Comment: no.  it is pretty much a fresh install from scratch.

Comment: @cesar.  the ports were not configured.  configuring them...

Comment: @cesar:  i configured the ports.  It must have worked.  Now I get a XML parsing error.  I will fix the parsing error just to make sure everything is square.

Comment: yup.  it was simply that the ports needed to be configured.  duh!  :)

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

Cesar has given the solution of opening up the ports 8080 and 4848 in the google cloud computing firewall configuration:

[How to open a specific port such as 9090 in Google Compute Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21065922/how-to-open-a-specific-port-such-as-9090-in-google-compute-engine)

I followed Cesar's link to get instructions on how to open up ports 8080 and 4848. The link led to instructions for an older version of google cloud computing's web console. To open the ports using the new GUI, first navigate to the Networking section, then navigate to firewalls ( i believe ).

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem, open required ports for the firewall, but still getting the same result: `problem loading ...`

I've noticed, that i tried opening `https://xx.xx.xx.xx:4848` instead of `http://xx.xx.xx.xx:4848`. So i changed protocol to `http` and it works