# Created mongodb cluster on google cloud, but unable to connect my application

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc

I am new to google cloud, I recently installed a mongodb cluster on google cloud instance. However I am unable to connect it from my application or Robomongo. Setting its configuration in the below manner in my spring mvc, I am using external ip as a host:

```
<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
</bean>
```

Its giving below exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Timed out after 10000 ms while waiting for a server that matches AnyServerSelector{}. 
Client view of cluster state is {type=Unknown, servers=[{address=104.196.32.97:27017, type=Unknown, state=Connecting}]; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 10000 ms while waiting for a server that matches AnyServerSelector{}. Client view of cluster state is {type=Unknown, servers=[{address=104.196.32.97:27017, type=Unknown, state=Connecting}]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MongoExceptionTranslator.java:73)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.potentiallyConvertRuntimeException(MongoTemplate.java:2011)
```

There is no tutorial available about integrating mongodb of gcloud with spring application.

Comment: This is how i am putting the mongo host and port details :   in spring config         <mongo:db-factory id="mongoDbFactory" host="104.196.32.97" port="27017" dbname="test"></mongo:db-factory>

Comment: open port 27017 in mongo cloud instance.

Comment: i did it with below command  but still no luck, is there any sample program I can refer to  >> gcloud compute firewall-rules create allow-mongodb --allow tcp:27017

Comment: are you able to telnet to the server on the port from ur local?

Comment: nope, please give me steps to how can I open the port and connect my java application to the mongodb hosted on gcloud, I wasted lot of time on this but still couldn't figure out the steps, really appreciate your help

Comment: find the steps in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21065922/how-to-open-a-specific-port-such-as-9090-in-google-compute-engine)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I finally moved to mlab and it was pretty easy to incorporate in my app.