# Cannot connect to TensorBoard page from Google Cloud VM instance

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, tensorboard

I tried to open TensorBoard page from running

`tensorboard --logdir=./Train_log/tb_train_log --port=8080` on Google Cloud Compute Engine VM instance. And the output web page `http:<usename>:8080` is not available. The error when I opened the page is :

```
Error: Could not connect to Cloud Shell on port 8080.
Ensure your server is listening on port 8080 and try again.
```

So I looked up to [Unable to open Tensorboard in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40106949/unable-to-open-tensorboard-in-browser) and [Can't open port 8080 on Google Compute Engine running Debian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25880703/cant-open-port-8080-on-google-compute-engine-running-debian).

Then I

```
1) set up the fire wall with creating a new rule as tcp:8080 and IP ranges 0.0.0.0/0.  
2) changed the port to 8080 and the default output 6006, changed the host to 0.0.0.0 and 127.0.0.1. Copy and paste corresponding address like http:0.0.0.0:8080 to google chrome. 
3) use web preview through google cloud shell to the port I set as above.
```

Also the output of `netstat -an | grep "LISTEN "` is

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

None of those worked, I wonder how to fix the problem ?

Any idea would be helpful !

Comment: In  Console > Networks > Firewall rules > edit your RULE, remove TARGET TAGS and then apply and see what happens maybe or alternatively you can try this link let me know if this doesn't work https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JmjqPpQdtW8

Answer (score 1):

I think the firewall configuration in GCP block the port 8080 firstly open the port 8080 in the GCP and after that execute this command :

```
tensorboard --logdir=./dir/log --port=8080 --bind_all
```