# Tensorboard showing nothing

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I am trying to use `tensorboard` but when I go on my localhost no graph  appears ...

I am doing the following steps :

```
1. Activate my conda environment in an other console (same as the one running tensorflow)
2. C:\####\workspace\training_demo>tensorboard --logdir=models/my_ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn
3. Output : 2021-03-04 18:50:28.546822: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
Serving TensorBoard on localhost; to expose to the network, use a proxy or pass --bind_all
TensorBoard 2.4.1 at http://localhost:6006/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
4. Open http://localhost:6006/ in google chrome
```

**TensorBoard Screen**

[image]

**models/my_ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn**

[image]

**Training Console Log**

```
INFO:tensorflow:Step 100 per-step time 1.411s loss=0.394
I0304 18:49:34.973733 11084 model_lib_v2.py:665] Step 100 per-step time 1.411s loss=0.394
INFO:tensorflow:Step 200 per-step time 1.419s loss=0.328
I0304 18:51:58.578679 11084 model_lib_v2.py:665] Step 200 per-step time 1.419s loss=0.328
INFO:tensorflow:Step 300 per-step time 1.481s loss=0.294
I0304 18:54:21.233937 11084 model_lib_v2.py:665] Step 300 per-step time 1.481s loss=0.294
```

**TensorBoard Page Excepted**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `tensorboard` does not work on **Google Chrome** , Using **Firefox** Solved My Issue.

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Thank you :), this is how to get it to work on chrome: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47287009/9525493

Comment: Tensorboard works fine in Google Chrome. You have probably connected to the wrong address or have another system config issue, as per the other post you have linked. Tensorboard is a Google product, so it is doubtful it would work better in Firefox (if anything, the experience will be nearly identical).