# K8n NodePort not available to public

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

If the Google Container Engine cluster has the service configured as `LoadBalancer` it's available to the general public as expected. But if I change that to `NodePort` it is not available as `<nodeIp>:<nodePort>`.
The service (web-service.yml) looks like that:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
 name: web
 labels:
   name: web
spec:
 type: NodePort
# type: LoadBalancer
 ports:
   - port: 80
     targetPort: 8080
     protocol: TCP
     nodePort: 30000
 selector:
   name: web
```

I would be very happy if someone could tell me why it isn't working.

Here is some background
The cluster consists of a MongoDB deployment (db-deployment.yml) with an according service (db-service.yml) and a Jetty deployment (web-deployment.yml) with an according service (web-service.yml)

It can be found [at GitHub](https://github.com/sandroboehme/sample-launchpad/tree/master/src/main/k8s/single-mongo) as part of [this project](https://github.com/sandroboehme/sample-launchpad) with the according Readme.md file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you open the port (30000) in the firewall? Also make sure you use the public IP of your VM.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21065922/how-to-open-a-specific-port-such-as-9090-in-google-compute-engine)