# Connection timeout on cluster.openBucket call with Couchbase / Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, couchbase, google-kubernetes-engine

I have deployed a 4 node Couchbase cluster using Google GKE.
The master node exposes ports 8091, 8093 to the Loadbaancer.
When connecting to the Loadbalancer IP (external) via a Java app to insert data, I get the timeout error with this stack:

```
Apr 04, 2017 3:32:15 PM com.couchbase.client.core.endpoint.AbstractEndpoint$2 operationComplete
WARNING: [null][ViewEndpoint]: Socket connect took longer than specified timeout.
Apr 04, 2017 3:32:15 PM com.couchbase.client.core.endpoint.AbstractEndpoint$2 operationComplete
WARNING: [null][KeyValueEndpoint]: Socket connect took longer than specified timeout.
Apr 04, 2017 3:32:15 PM com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise notifyListener0
WARNING: An exception was thrown by com.couchbase.client.core.endpoint.AbstractEndpoint$2.operationComplete()
rx.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: connection timed out: /10.4.0.3:8093
    at rx.Observable$26.onError(Observable.java:7955)
    at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber._onError(SafeSubscriber.java:159)
    at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber.onError(SafeSubscriber.java:120)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMap$1.onError(OperatorMap.java:48)
```

What's puzzling is that the stack shows 10.4.0.3:8093 which is actually the the IP of the docker container.
Appreciate all suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the firewall rules for the master node and the workers? You need to allow ingress for the ports you have set up.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21065922/how-to-open-a-specific-port-such-as-9090-in-google-compute-engine)

Comment: gke-auto-complete-a3114b27-all           default  10.4.0.0/14       udp,icmp,esp,ah,sctp,tcp
gke-auto-complete-a3114b27-ssh           default  35.184.136.11/32  tcp:22                                  gke-auto-complete-a3114b27-node
gke-auto-complete-a3114b27-vms           default  10.128.0.0/9      tcp:1-65535,udp:1-65535,icmp            gke-auto-complete-a3114b27-node
k8s-fw-a9b9a61a4198411e780b042010a8000d  default  0.0.0.0/0         tcp:8091,tcp:8093                       gke-auto-complete-a3114b27-node

Comment: Sorry, the above was the firewall-rules listing which was not formatted properly. I have exposed ports 8091 and 8093 to the LB only in the master node (actually, master pod), not the workers.

Comment: Update:
Increased timeout from 20 seconds to 60 seconds. Bucket openes. However get a lot of warnings thusly:

`WARNING: DNS Reverse Lookup of 10.4.1.5 is slow, took 4514ms
Apr 05, 2017 1:21:59 PM com.couchbase.client.core.node.CouchbaseNode <init>`

Again timeout when inserting data.
Kubedns is up and running.

Comment: What is the machine size you are using? Maybe it's a RAM issue?

Comment: Thanks so much for responding, appreciate it greatly!
The RAM size per node is 3 GB. The ssystem has 3 nodes and 4 Pods, but all the Pods are running on 2 nodes. The bucket which I'm trying to load is empty. 
I can open the Couchbase Console from the LB IP, query the travel-sample which I have also, and I see that the travel-sample data is rebalanced properly across the nodes. However, the SELECT query returns very slow.
The problem is this reverse DNS look-up, I think. It keeps timing out and takes 5 seconds per node. I think a 1 node system would be very fast without this reverse DNS.

Comment: Hm, 3GB should be enough. Can you create a printout of the following commands: `kubectl get events`, `kubectl describe pods`, `kubectl describe nodes`  (and `kubectl logs pod-name` for each pod)?

Comment: **Update**: I had Couchbase running on a docker container on my windows box. No Kubernetes. Just 1 node. My App connected to the bucket and inserted data. No problems at all. Created 1 more container. Added to cluster to form 2 node cluster. Rebalanced. Tried exact same app without changes. Now running into the same **timeout** error.

Comment: hmm....
Looks like [https://forums.couchbase.com/t/couchbase-issue-with-java-and-docker-setup/10896](https://forums.couchbase.com/t/couchbase-issue-with-java-and-docker-setup/10896)
The solution of modifying /etc/hosts may not work with kubernetes because of ephemeral IPs. The problem seems to be only with Java SDK. Incentive to move to Python.

Comment: Python is not a bad language :)