# Can't connect remotely to Jenkins being run on a Debian 8 VM

Tags: linux, jenkins, google-cloud-platform, debian-jessie

I've recently set up a Debian 8 Jessie VM on Google Cloud. I've installed Jenkins and have the service up and running(verified by "sudo service jenkins status"), yet I can't connect to the VM's external IP from another machine. I used to run Jenkins from my personal computer until I decided I needed a dedicated server to run it continuously. When I was running it on my personal machine I would just access localhost:8080 and the Jenkins dashboard would load fairly quickly. However, upon trying to access the external IP address of the VM running Jenkins, I'm usually greeted with "Connection refused" in my web browser.

At the suggestion of most posts I've seen regarding such issues, I've lifted all firewalls on the VM and have tried to ensure that the VM is listening at the correct IP address, but nothing seems to be able to change the outcome presented by my browser. Where does the issue most likely reside: the VM, Google Cloud, or Jenkins? I'm at a loss.

Comment: May fit better on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com)?

Answer (score 1):

My first guess is a connection/firewall issue. To test this, you could try a port forward using SSH: SSH into your server with a local port forward: `ssh -L 8080:localhost:8080 yourserver`. You should then be able to direct your web browser at *http://localhost:8080/* and your packets flow through the SSH connection. If that makes it work, have a good look at
[How to open a specific port such as 9090 in Google Compute Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21065922/how-to-open-a-specific-port-such-as-9090-in-google-compute-engine) . Or better yet, if you are the only one to use that Jenkins server, just keep using the SSH tunnel. It's much more secure than opening jenkins to the public world.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing tcpdump on the VM and doing a packet capture?  That way you can determine where the traffic is being dropped. If you don't see any traffic, then it is being dropped somewhere in the cloud before it gets to your VM.  If you are seeing traffic, then you need to determine is it Jenkins or some agent on the host (perhaps a firewall but you mentioned you cleared all the rules) ... I would suggest stopping the Jenkins service and then trying to access it again.  Do you get the same "Connection Refused" message?  If so, then it is something on the VM.  If not, then it something at the application layer, i.e. Jenkins.

Happy hunting!!!