# How to open a port or all ports for Google Cloud Compute Engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have an IOTA IRI instance running on a VM in GCP compute engine.
The instance is using port 14265 to communicate, and checking it locally by doing something like `curl http://localhost:14265` does respond.

I want to open this port to outside of the vm, so I set up a static IP, and a firewall rule to allow `tcp:14265; udp:14265` and still the port is not responding.

I even tried allowing all by doing:
[image]

But no luck. There is no port open except for 22 for ssh (looked in a [port scanner](https://mxtoolbox.com/PortScan.aspx))

I am aware it feels like a duplicate of [How to open a specific port such as 9090 in Google Compute Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21065922/how-to-open-a-specific-port-such-as-9090-in-google-compute-engine), but I did try those answers and they didn't solve it for me.

**EDIT:**

Running the two commands I was asked to run in an answer:

```
D:\Downloads> gcloud compute networks list
NAME     MODE  IPV4_RANGE  GATEWAY_IPV4
default  auto

D:\Downloads>gcloud compute instances describe instance-1 --zone europe-west1-b
canIpForward: false
cpuPlatform: Intel Sandy Bridge
creationTimestamp: '2017-08-22T09:33:12.240-07:00'
description: ''
disks:
- autoDelete: true
  boot: true
  deviceName: instance-1
  index: 0
  interface: SCSI
  kind: compute#attachedDisk
  licenses:
  - https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/ubuntu-os-cloud/global/licenses/ubuntu-1604-xenial
  mode: READ_WRITE
  source: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/iota-177616/zones/europe-west1-b/disks/instance-1
  type: PERSISTENT
id: '8895209582493819432'
kind: compute#instance
labelFingerprint: 42WmSpB8rSM=
machineType: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/iota-177616/zones/europe-west1-b/machineTypes/f1-micro
metadata:
  fingerprint: -pkE3KaIzLU=
  kind: compute#metadata
name: instance-1
networkInterfaces:
- accessConfigs:
  - kind: compute#accessConfig
    name: External NAT
    natIP: 35.187.9.204
    type: ONE_TO_ONE_NAT
  kind: compute#networkInterface
  name: nic0
  network: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/iota-177616/global/networks/default
  networkIP: 10.132.0.2
  subnetwork: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/iota-177616/regions/europe-west1/subnetworks/default
scheduling:
  automaticRestart: true
  onHostMaintenance: MIGRATE
  preemptible: false
selfLink: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/iota-177616/zones/europe-west1-b/instances/instance-1
serviceAccounts:
- email: 59105716861-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
  scopes:
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring.write
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/servicecontrol
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/service.management.readonly
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append
startRestricted: false
status: RUNNING
tags:
  fingerprint: 6smc4R4d39I=
  items:
  - http-server
  - https-server
zone: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/iota-177616/zones/europe-west1-b
```

Comment: How does your service listen on the port? Make sure it listens on 0.0.0.0:14265.

Comment: I don't really know how to figure that out. `curl` to `0.0.0.0:14265` and my local IP both return the same response as just `localhost:14265`

Comment: Hey, I am having the same problem. Can you please let me know how you solved this problem?

Comment: @PayalKothari Sorry, I didn't manage to

Answer (score 6):

It is difficult to give an exact answer without some diagnostics.

It could be that the rules are being created for a network and your instance is in a different network.

So, first of all, check the networks available in your project:

```
gcloud compute networks list
```

Secondly, check in which network your instance is located:

```
gcloud compute instances describe [Instance Name] --zone [Zone]
```

Check the firewall rules being applied to the network used by your instance:

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules list
```

Also check that the target tags are the appropriate ones.

---

As you can see there are not tags applied to the VM, although the rules should apply if you target it to all vm's itis a good practice to do it.

1. Edit your VM and add a tag(Ex. frontserver)

   `gcloud compute instances add-tags [INSTANCE NAME] --zone [ZONE] --tags frontserver`
2. Now create the firewall rule and apply it to the tag created

   `gcloud beta compute firewall-rules create [NAME_OF_THE_RULE] --direction=INGRESS --priority=1000 --network=default --allow=all --source-ranges=0.0.0.0/0 --target-tags=frontserver`

Check this it it works you can run an update to restrict it to the desired ports and protocols and your source IP

```
gcloud beta compute firewall-rules update [NAME_OF_THE_RULE] --direction=INGRESS --priority=1000 --network=default --allow=tcp:--source-ranges=[your_source_IP] --target-tags=frontserver
```

Hope this helps, further info is found [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpc/using-firewalls) with examples

Comment: Thanks. I ran those and the result is in the questions's edit.