# Port 5432 is closed on Google Compute Engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, google-app-engine, ubuntu

Currently I need to establish remote connection with my server (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS).
I Install Postgresql and I made the following settings:

**/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/postgresql.conf:**

```
listen_addresses='*'
```

**/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/pg_hba.conf:**

```
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
```

If run this command: **netstat -anpt | grep LISTEN** 
shows the port is listening
[image]

but when I try to establish the connection, I have this error:
[image]

And this [tool](http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/) tells me that the port is closed:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Allowing only on Configurations of Postgresql server is not enough. You need to add a firewall rule in google compute engine. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21065922/how-to-open-a-specific-port-such-as-9090-in-google-compute-engine)

Firewall rules control incoming or outgoing traffic to an instance. By default, incoming traffic from outside your network is blocked.

Comment: It works, Thank you!!
[Config from gCloud](https://imgur.com/a/nmJd6)
[info from my console](https://imgur.com/a/Ee2QK)