# Setting up Django on a clean VM: issue linking runserver to VM's ip

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm setting up my Django site on a clean Ubuntu VM. Gone through the process of installing the necessary tools, I follow [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04) tutorial and apart from the additional python packages I've added for my site it's the same process.

According to this instructional guide to check whether everything is running smoothly you run `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` and it should then run on the IP:8000 of the site.

[image]

above is the instance of this running

[image]

and this above shows the external ip of the google cloud instance running this.

However when i try to visit `http://35.227.49.155:8000/` I get `This site can't be reached` and it's double confirmed with no activity on the shell on a request picked up.

**UPDATE**

Since as suggested that likely google cloud's firewall might be blocking this I've tried made this port open

[image]

but still can't get it to work.

Comment: Did you configure the VM to expose port 8000 to the public internet?

Comment: yes using `sudo ufw allow 8000`

Comment: It's more than just that though. Google probably has your VM behind a firewall. You'll likely need to configure this port to be open on Google's console somewhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21065922/how-to-open-a-specific-port-such-as-9090-in-google-compute-engine

Comment: let me try that

Comment: `muiruri_samuel@pluscolor:~$ sudo gcloud compute firewall-rules create allow_8000 --allow tcp:8000 --sou
rce-tags=pluscolor --source-ranges=0.0.0.0/0
Creating firewall...failed.                                                                           
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.firewall-rules.create) Could not fetch resource:
 - Insufficient Permission`

Comment: tried the command `sudo gcloud compute firewall-rules create allow_8000 --allow tcp:8000 --source-tags=pluscolor --source-ranges=0.0.0.0/0` I get the error Insufficient Permission

Comment: That's an issue for Google Cloud support then: https://cloud.google.com/support/