# How to open a specific port such as 9090 in Google Compute Engine using Python

Tags: python, google-compute-engine

I am using Python to interact with Google Compute Engine. I am able to create/stop machines using Python directly.  I have used [sample code from GoogleCloudPlatform](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/compute/api/create_instance.py) for this purpose and it is working fine.

Now I want to open some ports to interact with machine from outside world using the Python API.

This related question already tells [how to open a specific port from Google console web and gcloud command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21065922/how-to-open-a-specific-port-such-as-9090-in-google-compute-engine), so my question is specifically how to do it with the Python API.

Comment: While I'm no Python guru, it might be worth checking out the API explorer to see how to construct API calls for inserting firewall rules here https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/firewall/m/compute/v1/compute.firewalls.insert  and the API call to delete firewall rules here https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/firewall/m/compute/beta/compute.firewalls.delete . There is also the google-api-python-client which may also be helpful  https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client .

Answer (score 2):

Here's some sample code to get you started, but I recommend you review the [entire firewalls portion](http://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/compute_v1.firewalls.html) of the compute API to make sure you use all the options you need:

This runs successfully on cloud shell, which uses application default credentials.  You might need to [authenticate in a different way](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production).

```py
import googleapiclient.discovery

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MY_PROJECT = 'your-project-name'

    # Get the firewalls resource
    firewalls = googleapiclient.discovery.build('compute', 'v1').firewalls()

    # Build the REST parameters for a port 9090 ingress allow-all firewall.
    firewall_definition = {
      "name": "default-allow-9090",
      "direction": "INGRESS",
      # targetTags: "add tags here if you need them -- default is apply to all",
      "sourceRanges" : "0.0.0.0/0",
      "allowed": { "IPProtocol": "tcp", "ports": [ 9090 ] },
      "priority": 1000,
      "network": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/%s/global/networks/default" % MY_PROJECT,
    }

    # Execute the call.
    result = firewalls.insert(project=MY_PROJECT, body=firewall_definition).execute()

    # View Response
    print(result)
```