# How to preview web apps on GCloud

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, port, grafana, graphite

I have Grafana hosted on Google Cloud Platform using docker - https://github.com/kamon-io/docker-grafana-graphite. I confirmed docker is running on GCE and as GCE only allows port 8080 upwards I change the Grafana port to 8080. I tried previewing using the console, and it returned

```
Error: Could not connect to Cloud Shell on port 8080.
Ensure your server is listening on port 8080 and try again.
```

This error does not pertain to this app alone but all the apps I have hosted on GCE, so I seeking a valid way to preview webapps on GCE.
This is the docker file docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  grafana_graphite:
    build: .
    image: kamon/grafana_graphite
    container_name: kamon-grafana-dashboard
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
      - '8181:8181'
      - '8125:8125/udp'
      - '8126:8126'
      - '2003:2003'
    volumes:
      - ./data/whisper:/opt/graphite/storage/whisper
      - ./data/grafana:/opt/grafana/data
      - ./log/graphite:/opt/graphite/storage/log
      - ./log/supervisor:/var/log/supervisor
```

Comment: Did you check GCloud's firewall configurations?

Comment: Yes. I have opened all the ports necessary. Followed this tutorial - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-with-ufw-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: I'm afraid this is not enough. The cloud also has restrictions on opening ports. You need not only to open the port with ufw on your system but also add accepting rule for the port in the admin panel of the cloud. At least it's true for AWS, not sure if GCloud is the same story.

Comment: Find this question, might be helpful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21065922/how-to-open-a-specific-port-such-as-9090-in-google-compute-engine

Comment: O thanks. I'll give it a shot. Appreciate.

Comment: Still the same. Returned the same error.

Comment: Alright, can you paste related configs here?

Comment: Yes. I just did added it to the main post body. Thanks.

Comment: But where is port 8080? You mentioned that the Grafana is on port 8080.

Comment: Sorry, was a mistake, didn't this is a local copy I have. Have edited it to reflect 8080 on the server.

Comment: The config file looks good to me. Got no idea why this error is still happening. Double check your entire deployment process?

Comment: Ok. I'll. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

The Grafana backend binds to port 3000 by default, even if you open the firewall on port 8080 it may not work. You have to use one of the following  alternatives:

1. Redirect port 8080 to the Grafana port using:
   $ sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 8080 -j REDIRECT --to- port 3000
2. Put a webserver like Nginx or Apache in front of Grafana and have them proxy requests to Grafana.

Further information on Grafana configurations options can be found on this [documentation](http://docs.grafana.org/installation/configuration/) link.