# I'm trying to Run Docker Compose with Docker on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, docker-compose

I new to docker and GCP.
I followed the instructions given [here](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/docker-compose-on-container-optimized-os)

My docker-compose.yml file looks like this:

```
version: '3'
services: 
  backend:
    image: com.xyz.backend:v1
    build: ./server/
    ports: 
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - ./server:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
  frontend:
    image: com.xyz.frontend:v1
    build: ./client/
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./client:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    links:
      - backend
```

Docker file => client/Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8.15.0-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ENV NODE_PATH=/node_modules

ENV PATH=$PATH:/node_modules/.bin

COPY package.json /usr/src/app

RUN npm i -g npm-check-updates

RUN ncu -u

RUN npm install

COPY . /usr/src/app

ENV PORT 3000

EXPOSE 3000

RUN pwd

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Docker file => server/Dockerfile

```
FROM node:8.15.0-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ENV NODE_PATH=/node_modules

ENV PATH=$PATH:/node_modules/.bin

RUN npm install -g nodemon

COPY package.json /usr/src/app

RUN npm i -g npm-check-updates

RUN ncu -u

RUN npm install

COPY . /usr/src/app

ENV PORT 5000

EXPOSE 5000

RUN pwd

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

cloudbuild.yaml

```
steps:
- name: ‘docker/compose:1.23.2’
  args: [‘up’, ‘-d’]
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['tag', 'workspace_app:latest', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA']
images: ['gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA']
```

Project Structure:

```
Project
↳ client
   ↳ Dockerfile
  server
   ↳ Dockerfile

  README.md
  Dockerfile
  cloudbuild.yaml
  docker-compose.yml
```

When I try to run this in gcp no errors are thrown but I couldn't access using the public ip.

When I'm running it locally it runs fine.

I run the docker using the following command

```
docker run     -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock     -v "$PWD:$PWD"     -w="$PWD"   docker/compose:1.23.2 up
```

I tried setting the port also like:

```
docker run     -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock     -v "$PWD:$PWD"     -w="$PWD"  -p 8080:3000   docker/compose:1.23.2 up
```

Couldn't find where the problem is.
Please advice.. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like a firewall issue.

The example you followed [listens to connections on port 80](https://github.com/docker/dockercloud-hello-world/blob/master/docker-cloud.yml#L4) while your application uses port 3000 and 5000.
GCP comes with a set of default firewall rules where ports for some standard protocols like HTTP are accessible, but you will need to create a new firewall to allow access for the relevant ports of your app.

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21068402/5539618) about creating firewall rules for specific ports.