# Can't connect to MySQL Docker hosted on GCP Kubernetes Engine

Tags: python, mysql, docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I want to connect to MySQL docker hosted on GCP Kubernetes through Python to edit a database.
I encounter the error:

```
2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '35.200.250.69' ([Errno 61] Connection refused)"
```

I've tried also to connect throught MySQL, not working either

### Docker environment

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM mysql:latest
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD password


# Derived from official mysql image (our base image)
FROM mysql
# Add a database
ENV MYSQL_DATABASE test-db
ENV MYSQL_USER=dbuser
ENV MYSQL_PASSWORD=dbpassword

# Add the content of the sql-scripts/ directory to your image
# All scripts in docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ are automatically
# executed during container startup
COPY ./sql-scripts/ /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
EXPOSE 50050
CMD echo "This is a test." | wc -
CMD ["mysqld"]
```

The *sql-scripts* folder content 2 files in it:

```
CREATE USER 'newuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'newpassword';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * to 'newuser'@'%';
```

and

```
CREATE DATABASE test_db;
```

### Setting up GCP

I launch the container with the following command:

```
kubectl run test-mysql --image=gcr.io/data-sandbox-196216/test-mysql:latest --port=50050 --env="MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root_password"
```

on GCP, the container seems running properly:

```
NAME         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)           AGE
test-mysql   LoadBalancer   10.19.249.10   35.200.250.69   50050:30626/TCP   2m
```

### Connect with Python

And the python file to connect to the MySQL:

```
import sqlalchemy as db

# specify database configurations
config = {
    'host': '35.200.250.69',
    'port': 50050,
    'user': 'root',
    'password': 'root_password',
    'database': 'test_db'
}
db_user = config.get('user')
db_pwd = config.get('password')
db_host = config.get('host')
db_port = config.get('port')
db_name = config.get('database')
# specify connection string
connection_str = f'mysql+pymysql://{db_user}:{db_pwd}@{db_host}:{db_port}/{db_name}'
# connect to database
engine = db.create_engine(connection_str)
connection = engine.connect()
```

### What I want to do

I would like to be able to write this MySQL database with Python, and read it on PowerBI.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: is firewall enabled to allow tcp traffic from  30626 port

Comment: Thanks for your answer! How do I check the firewall? Is it on GCP side or on my local computer? (I am on Mac OS btw)

Comment: https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/firewalls/list

Comment: [GCP screenshot](https://imgur.com/CEilm5p)
Sorry for the dumb question, I am on GCP, and for the IP range, which one should I choose? External IP?     
First time I use this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21065922/how-to-open-a-specific-port-such-as-9090-in-google-compute-engine

Comment: I did the following:  
`gcloud compute firewall-rules create sql-rule --allow=tcp:30626`
    
Got the result:    
[Screenshot](https://imgur.com/lCx3bTb), but i still can't connect to it.. Do I need to restart the docker?

Comment: whats the output of `kubectl describe deploy test-mysql  --all-namespaces`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have exposed port **50050** while MySQL server by default is listening port **3306**

**Option I.** Change default port in `my.cfg` and set `port=50050`

**Option II.** Expose default MySQL port

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mysql:latest
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD password


# Derived from official mysql image (our base image)
FROM mysql
# Add a database
ENV MYSQL_DATABASE test-db
ENV MYSQL_USER=dbuser
ENV MYSQL_PASSWORD=dbpassword

# Add the content of the sql-scripts/ directory to your image
# All scripts in docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ are automatically
# executed during container startup
COPY ./sql-scripts/ /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
EXPOSE 3306
CMD echo "This is a test." | wc -
CMD ["mysqld"]
```

Start container:

```
kubectl run test-mysql --image=gcr.io/data-sandbox-196216/test-mysql:latest --port=3306 --env="MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root_password"
```