# Google windows instance not enabling 445/139 port even though firewall rule is defined to allow

Tags: windows, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud, smb

I'm creating a google windows instance for which i need to enable SMB [File and Printer Sharing] 445 and 139 ports.
I have created a firewall rule under "VPC Network" => Firewall rules

But still created windows instance does not have 445 or 139 port enable.

Firewall rule is as below:

"default-allow-smb
Ingress
Apply to all
IP ranges: 0.0.0.0/0
tcp:445,139
Allow
65534
default"

When I login to windows instance via RDP and check under "Control Panel" => System and Security => Windows Firewall => Advance Settings => Inbound Rules : "File and Printer Sharing" (SMB-in) shows DISABLED only.

Created google windows instance on google cloud console shows "default-allow-smb" firewall rule under network details.
[Firewall Rule is as below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQwg3.png)

[Firewall Rule details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vziYt.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Windows Environment inside your Google Compute Engine VM instance

I am using Windows Server 2019 Datacenter
Server with Desktop Experience, x64 built on 20190910 Google Compute Engine VM instance

> I used **[Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/file-server/best-practices-analyzer/smb-open-file-sharing-ports)** and followed the steps to open the firewall ports to enable file and printer sharing. Currently for me, **File and Printer Sharing (SMB-In)** is disabled. However, there is an **"Enable Rule"** button on the right-hand side that you can click on to enable the rule.

[image]

> Then, it should **enable** the rule, just like it shows here:

[image]

> As you can see **Enabled field** is set to **Yes**

[image]

### Firewall Rules for your Google Compute Engine VM instance

> If you would like to double check whether you properly set up your Firewall Rules, you could check **[How to open a specific port in Google Compute Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21065922/how-to-open-a-specific-port-such-as-9090-in-google-compute-engine/55933943#55933943)** or check the **[official Google Documentation for Firewall Rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls)**

Comment: Thanks sllopis . 
I can do this manually like you mentioned to click on "Enable Rule" , but i want it to be enabled automatically by default when I create Google windows Instance with the firewall rule configured.

Comment: Oh I see, you can achieve this by using a [startup script for Windows instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript#providing_a_startup_script_for_windows_instances), which will perform automated tasks every time your instance boots up. Hope it helps you.

Comment: @SrushtiTrivedi - PowerShell to enable firewall rule: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netsecurity/enable-netfirewallrule

Comment: Thanks @sllopis and @John Hanley
Adding Power Shell startup script with 'windows-startup-script-url' worked. 
```
{'metadata': { 'items': [{
                                                    'key': 'windows-startup-script-url',
                                                    'value': "gs://<path-to-script>/enable_port.ps1"
                                                }]
                                    }

Comment: Hi Srushti Trivedi, could you accept the answer, so it can help the community locate it better?