# Can't access CyberPanel login on GCP with OpenLiteSpeed

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, litespeed

I've installed Cyber Panel with OpenLiteSpeed on a GCP micro instance with CentOS7, and although I can access the OpenLiteSpeed Control Panel I can't access the Cyber Panel login, the latter timesout. I didn't use the 1-click CyberPanel image, instead I used:

```
wget -O installer.sh https://cyberpanel.net/install.sh
```

I've opened ports 7080 and 8090 as shown in the nmap report below.

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1025/openlitespeed        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1025/openlitespeed         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8090            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1037/lscpd (lscpd -
```

I saw another similar post from 2018 but without a solution at https://forums.cyberpanel.net/discussion/601/cyberpanel-cannot-be-accessed-from-google-cloud-platform

I didn't realise that OpenLiteSpeed came with it's own control panel, I had thought it would be simply a replacement for Apache, so I had thought I would just use CyberPanel to setup accounts/virtual hosts etc.

Any help in tracing the issue would be greatly appreciated. I only have limited experience with Linux/CentOS/Apache and no experience with OpenLireSpeed and CyberPanel.

Comment: Have you run `installer.sh`? (i.e. `chmod +x installer.sh && ./installer.sh`)

Comment: this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21065922/how-to-open-a-specific-port-such-as-9090-in-google-compute-engine) should help you , you have to open 8090 port in GCP firewall.

Comment: Yes I did ran chmod 755 installer.sh and sh installer.sh. @qtwrk like I said in my notes I have opened ports 7080 and 8090.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noted from another post that someone said installing using sudo would not work, so I deleted the instance, recreated, and installed using root user; made no difference.

At the end of the install I had missed seeing the list of ports that are required to be opened:

> Please make sure you have opened following port for both in/out:
>   TCP: 8090 for CyberPanel
>   TCP: 80, TCP: 443 and UDP: 443 for webserver
>   TCP: 21 and TCP: 40110-40210 for FTP
>   TCP: 25, TCP: 587, TCP: 465, TCP: 110, TCP: 143 and TCP: 993 for mail service
>   TCP: 53 and UDP: 53 for DNS service

Although I had opened 7080 and 8090, I had not opened

> TCP: 53 and UDP: 53 for DNS service

and

> UDP: 443 for webserver

I believe it was opening UDP:443 that allowed the Cyber Panel login page load.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
curl -I -XGET -k https://127.0.0.1:8090
```

if above returns 200/301/302 , then means panel page is OK

then

```
curl -I -XGET -k https://SERVER_PUBLIC_IP:8090
```

if above returns timeout or any error , that basically indicates firewall blocking it

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't see this post yesterday, the page hadn't refreshed. However port 8090 was definately already open.