# Accessing host from external IP address

Tags: ubuntu, ip, google-compute-engine, ip-address, google-cloud-networking

I am using Google Cloud Compute Engine to install airflow and keep it up and running. The installation was fine and now it is running on host : 0.0.0.0:8080

I have an external IP address for this VM instance, however, I am not able to open this port through this port. I have checked firewall rules, HTTP/HTTPS traffic allowance, and everything. Everything looks fine. Any tips on why it should happen and how to solve it?

Thanks in advance :)

[image: From VPC - Firewall rules]
[image: From VM instance]

Comment: have you enabled TCP traffic on 8080 port? Can you show firewall rule?

Comment: @MR.K I have added images

Comment: You only allowed 80 and 443. You need to allow TCP:8080 port explicitly.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you please share it as an answer? @MR.K

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to open a specific port such as 9090 in Google Compute Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21065922/how-to-open-a-specific-port-such-as-9090-in-google-compute-engine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to open the TCP:8080 port for allowing the external traffic using firewall rule.

Please refer following gcloud command to create firewall rule:

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules create <RULE NAME> --direction=INGRESS --priority=1000 --network=default --action=ALLOW --rules=tcp:8080 --source-ranges=0.0.0.0/0 --target-tags=<TAG FOR TARGET VM>
```

For more details on how to create firewall rules using GCP console (or other options) please see [Creating Firewall Rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls#creating_firewall_rules)

Answer (score 1):

Port 8080 is not a HTTP(80) or HTTPS(443) port.
You need to go VPC --> Firewall Rules and then create a new rule which allows access to `tcp:8080` from all the location you want to access.

You can also put your VM tag under `target destination` if you want to just allow this firewall rule for this specific instance.

Hope this helps.